# CreateWindowEx creates old (Windows 7) style border on Windows 10

Tags: c++, createwindowex, window-style

Whenever I create a window with `CreateWindowEx(...)` (exact parameters can be found in the code below), it shows up like an old style window:

[image: old style window]

Only when I start it on a remote desktop, close the connection and reconnect, it changes to the desired Windows 10 style:

[image: new style window]

Does it have something to do with the several `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` messages the application receives when doing this?

Obviously, I want the window to have a modern style upon creation, and not after handling some message.

I've tried different combinations of `WS_...` style arguments. Oddly enough, the application only reliably shows up with `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE`.

I've tried `ShowWindow` (with various arguments) and `UpdateWindow` in both orders.

I've also tried messing with the target platform and toolset, but to no avail (using VS2015, v140).

Code snippet:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc = {sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), NULL, WindowController::globalEventProcessor, 
                 0L, 0L, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL,
                 LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW), NULL, NULL,
                 _T("Window"), NULL};
RegisterClassEx(&wc);

HWND handle = CreateWindowEx(
            NULL,
            wc.lpszClassName,
            _T("Test"),
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            parentWindow ? parentWindow->getHandle() : NULL,
            NULL,
            wc.hInstance,
            reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(this)
);

if (handle != NULL)
{
    ... // resizing the window's contents
    UpdateWindow(handle);
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but you might need an application manifest.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I've followed the guides to add a manifest in VS2015, but either I'm doing something wrong, or it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely enough, the solution seems to be to remove `WS_VISIBLE` from the style flags, and show the window manually:

```
if (handle != NULL)
{
    ... // resizing the window's contents
    ShowWindow(handle, 1); /* Add this */
    UpdateWindow(handle);
}
```

Which I'm 100% sure I've tried already, but suddenly works. Whatever...